# Uninstaller generated by install4J requires admin privs on Windows 10

Tags: install4j

I've generated an installer for my desktop app using install4j. The installer installs to a hidden file in the user's home directory. When installing/uninstalling/updating as a non-admin user on Windows 7 everything is great, but Windows 10 is different in these ways using the same installer:

1) On Windows 10 running the uninstaller from Control Panels -> Apps & features immediately prompts for an admin password. I can manually run the installer as non-admin user and it works fine - does not prompt for escalation and correctly uninstalls.
2) On Windows 10 the uninstaller link does not appear in the program group as it does in Windows 7. This was going to be my workaround.

I've checked permissions, the registry, and the installer for anything that might be causing this behavior on Windows 10 but haven't found anything.

Has anyone experienced or can anyone confirm this behavior? Is there a workaround I can do so that the user can uninstall my application from the Windows control panel without admin rights?

These tests were done using Windows 7 64 bit and Windows 10 64 bit.

Thank you!

Comment: This is not caused by install4j, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469595/how-to-prevent-uninstaller-elevating-for-standard-windows-10-user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent uninstaller elevating for Standard Windows 10 user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469595/how-to-prevent-uninstaller-elevating-for-standard-windows-10-user)